# unity shader : Applying ZOrder to sprite renderer conditionally

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, unity3d-2dtools

[image]

here's scene object info of above figure.
all of object's renderer is 'SpriteRenderer', and Material is 'Sprites-Default'.

[A (Car)]
OrderInLayer : 302
Local Z Position : -9.8

[B (Land)]
OrderInLayer : 270
Local Z Position : -9

[C1, C2 (Land)]
OrderInLayer : 300
Local Z Position : -10

[D (Land)]
OrderInLayer : 330
Local Z Position : -11

I hope that you do not obstruct the 'D' is 'A' in the above situation.

But such a situation can not use OrderInLayer.

So I'm not sure at all that you will use the same shader.

Help!

Comment: Why are you suffering yourself? I've seen many questions about this game you are making. You should do this with 3D instead of 2D. Just create 3D models and texture them with the images from the post above.

Comment: no i need to solve this problem in 2d